# How can i update data in c#

Tags: c#, executenonquery

1. I'm working in Visual Studio 2019 In c
2. I have problem with updating data to database
3. I use local Visual Studio SQL database

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
String source = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Szabolcs\Documents\Adatbázis Kezelés2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);
con.Open();

```
        String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE ID = "+ int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            textBox2.Text = (dr["Name"].ToString());
            textBox3.Text = (dr["Kor"].ToString());
            label4.Text = (dr["Kor"].ToString());
            label5.Text = (dr["Kor"].ToString());

            int s = 11;
            string y = (dr["Kor"].ToString());

            label4.Text = (dr["Kor"].ToString());
            x = Int32.Parse(label4.Text);
            x = x + 0;

            label6.Text = (x.ToString());
            
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String source = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Szabolcs\Documents\Adatbázis Kezelés2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);
        con.Open();
        x = x + 1;
        label6.Text = (x.ToString());
        String st = "UPDATE supplier SET Kor = " + label6.Text + " WHERE Id = " + textBox1.Text;
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Almost the same as you did in button1 except typically you use `ExecuteNonQuery()` for an UPDATE. Though if my guess is correct, you will have a sql syntax error because you have not quoted `label6.Text`.

Comment: The problem is that SQL is not "Uppdating" the data. Edit: Program is working just not uppdate the data

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these lines

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(st, con);
int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Please put a breakpoint and check the value of `st`, is it generating the valid query.

I would suggest to use parameterized query to avoid sql injection.

Also, please avoid using `Select *`, please use columns.

Comment: There is have error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'supplier'.'

Comment: Do you have supplier table? Or check your connection string, are you pointing to the right database?

Comment: I have "supplier" here: `String st = "UPDATE supplier SET Kor = " + label6.Text + " WHERE Id = " + textBox1.Text;`

Comment: So is supplier table present in database?

Comment: Here have a picture [link](https://imgur.com/a1ieLQq)

Comment: @Szabolcs that table is literally named "Table", not supplier.

Comment: Ohh... Its working. Thank you for help. Have a nice day